# Loading data to Postgres RDS is still slow after tuning parameters

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

We have created a RDS postgres instance (m4.xlarge) with 200GB storage (Provisioned IOPS). We are trying to upload data from company data mart to the 23 tables in RDS using DataStage. However the uploads are quite slow. It takes about 6 hours to load 400K records.

Then I started tuning the following parameters according to [Best Practices for Working with PostgreSQL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.PostgreSQL):

```
autovacuum  0
checkpoint_completion_target  0.9
checkpoint_timeout  3600
maintenance_work_mem  {DBInstanceClassMemory/16384}
max_wal_size  3145728
synchronous_commit  off
```

Other than these, I also turned off `multi AZ` and back-up. SSL is enabled though, not sure this will change anything. However, after all the changes, still not much improvement. DataStage is uploading data in parallel already ~12 threads. Write IOPS is around 40/sec. Is this value normal? Is there anything else I can do to speed up the data transfer?

Comment: Is your RDS instance publically accessible? Is it going through NAT or other network bottlenecks (proxies, VPN, etc)

Comment: One more thing.. do you have a bunch of indexes still enabled? Also, how big is your data (meg, not rows)

Comment: @JoeLove the instance is publicly accessible no proxy or vpn, etc. Total data is about 50GB. About 10GB data got loaded in 5 hours.

Comment: What's the speed of your internet connection (upload)? Test on speedtest.net

Comment: Are you loading the data from somewhere outside of AWS?  If you have not copied your data to an EC2 instance and tried loading it from there, you are probably seeing the impact of the round-trip time between you and RDS.  Alternately, try even more threads to partially compensate for the round-trip.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes data is being transfered from inside company firewall to RDS directly. So I guess it is normal the uploads is slow. Having more threads did improve the transfer a little bit.

Comment: At a guess what's happening here is that DataStage is doing a full round-trip for every row inserted, or for batches of inserts at least. That's going to perform terribly. It's consistent with the results shown: 21600 seconds for 400000 records = 18 records/second, or 50ms/record. If your network latency is fairly low, this could be about right for one round trip per record, but it's more likely that you're seeing round trips per batch of 10 or 100 records. Increase batch sizes if you can, or better, get it to use PostgreSQL's `COPY` protocol to stream the input.

Comment: @CraigRinger when you and others say `roundtrip`, what does it mean exactly? What rds parameter is associated with batch size? Since it is from MS SQL server to RDS postgres, we can't use `COPY` protocol.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time

Comment: Batch size, if it does batching at all, will be determined by your ETL tool DataStage. Not by RDS PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgresql, you're going to have to wait 1 full round trip (latency) for each insert statement written. This latency is the latency between the database all the way to the machine where the data is being loaded from.

In AWS you have many options to improve performance.

1. For starters, you can load your raw data onto an EC2 instance and start importing from there, however, you will likely not be able to use your dataStage tool unless it can be loaded directly on the ec2 instance.
2. You can configure dataStage to use batch processing where each insert statement actually contains many rows.. generally, the more, the faster.
3. disable data compression and make sure you've done everything you can to minimize latency between the two endpoints.